# Symmetric expression not recognized

Tags: tensors

Why the following symmetric tensor is not recognized by `TensorSymmetry`?

```
$Assumptions = {
  Element[a, Vectors[3, Reals]],
  Element[b, Vectors[3, Reals]]
  };

TensorSymmetry[TensorProduct[a, b] + TensorProduct[b, a]]
(* {} *)
```

`TensorReduce`, applied to the argument or to the result, does not change anything.

But

```
TensorTranspose[TensorProduct[a, b] + TensorProduct[b, a], {1, 2}] == 
  TensorProduct[a, b] + TensorProduct[b, a]
(* True *)
```